# How to import the data from excel to the .mdb access file?

Tags: vb.net

Here i m have some problem were export the data which in `excel` to the format of `.mdb`. i m trying the code were showing below, but it shows the messageBox

> Import Failed, correct Column name in the sheet!

Error Message:

> The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

is there anyone can help me.

Best Regards,
Thanes

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' delete the file with the same and create a new access file
    If File.Exists("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test\CA\book.mdb") Then
        File.Delete("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test\CA\book.mdb")
    End If

    Dim _accessData As Access.Application
    _accessData = New Access.Application()
    _accessData.Visible = False
    _accessData.NewCurrentDatabase("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test\CA\book.mdb", Access.AcNewDatabaseFormat.acNewDatabaseFormatAccess2000, , , )

    _accessData.CloseCurrentDatabase()
    _accessData.Quit(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveAll)
    _accessData = Nothing

    ' initialize the connect string
    Dim _filename As String = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test\CA\test.xls"
    Dim _conn As String
    _conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test\CA\test.xls" & _filename & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Dim _connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_conn)

    'Use OledbCommand object to select all the data from sheet1 and execute an ExecuteNonQuery to import data into Book.mdb.
    Dim _command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
    _command.Connection = _connection

    Try
        _command.CommandText = "SELECT * INTO [MS Access;Database=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test\CA\book.mdb].[Sheet1] FROM [Sheet1$A4:D]"
        _connection.Open()
        _command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        _connection.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("The import is complete!")

    Catch e1 As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Import Failed, correct Column name in the sheet!" & Environment.NewLine & "Error Message:" & Environment.NewLine & e1.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

*Note: the program is can create .mdb file, but cannot import the excel data into it.

Answer (score 0):

i m settle it rdy...thank anyway for the help...

```
Public Class Form1
    Private DBPath As String
    Private conn As OleDbConnection
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ''delete the file with the same and create a new access file
        If File.Exists("C:\Users\Inari Admin\Desktop\test\CA\test.mdb") Then
            File.Delete("C:\Users\Inari Admin\Desktop\test\CA\test.mdb")
        End If

DBPath = "C:\Users\Inari Admin\Desktop\test\CA\test.mdb"

        ' create DB via ADOX if not exists
        ' NOTE: to use ADOX add reference to COM Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.6 for DDL and Security!
        If Not File.Exists(DBPath) Then
            Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog()
            cat.Create(Convert.ToString("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=") & DBPath)
            cat = Nothing

        End If

        conn = New OleDbConnection(Convert.ToString("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=") & DBPath)
        conn.Open()

        Try
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [test] ([id] COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, [num] INT, [name] MEMO, [no] INT);", conn)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex IsNot Nothing Then
                ex = Nothing

            End If
        End Try

        ' initialize the connect string
        Dim _filename As String = "C:\Users\Inari Admin\Desktop\test\CA\test.xls"
        Dim _conn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & _filename & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

        Dim _connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_conn)

        'Use OledbCommand object to select all the data from sheet1 and execute an ExecuteNonQuery to import data into test.mdb.
        Dim _command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
        _command.Connection = _connection

        Try
            Using conn As New OleDbConnection(_conn)
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
                    cmd.Connection = conn
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [MS Access;Database=" + DBPath + "].[test] SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
                    conn.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
            '_command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
            '_connection.Open()
            '_command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            '_connection.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("The import is complete!")

        Catch e1 As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Import Failed, correct Column name in the sheet!" & Environment.NewLine & "Error Message:" & Environment.NewLine & e1.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```